# Query history informix isql

Tags: informix, isql

We are using informix db on linux operating system.Is there a way we can know history of queries that have been executed through isql ?

Answer (score 1):

The Informix server has a feature for SQL tracing that is enabled with the SQLTRACE onconfig parameter. This can be set to collect various levels of information relating to executed statements including the statement text. This is maintained in an in-memory circular buffer so the information would need to be extracted from this buffer and stored separately if you wanted to maintain a permanent history.

There is more information on this feature in the Informix Adminstrator's Guide at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.admin.doc/ids_admin_1126.htm